# boostrap fix full width element with content aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div which becomes `fixed` when it is scrolled to. I would like this div to go full width when it is in it's `fixed` state. I have done this by setting `width: 100%` to the div in question. The problem is I would like the content of the div to still line up with the content of the page, instead of going to the left. I would like to be able to do this without changing the current html markup.

---

**Example**: Full width when scrolled to and in `fixed` state.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19335/

---

**Example**: If I add padding left to bring the content inwards this works. The problem is the padding left could be any number -is there a way of reliably working this out?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19337/

---

CSS:

```
#myDiv.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($('#myDivWrapper'))) {
    if (!initSet) {
      initSet = true;
    }
    $("#myDiv").removeClass('fixed');
  } else if (initSet) {
    $("#myDiv").addClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

Comment: delete 

left: 0; and it should do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra `.container` div inside the `#myDiv` and adjust the padding as and when the fixing takes place.

```
<div id="myDivWrapper">
    <div id="myDiv">
      <div class="container">
        <p>
          This should be fixed once it comes into view and then goes out of view.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


#myDiv .container {
  padding: 0;
}

#myDiv.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#myDiv.fixed .container {
padding: 0 15px;
}
```

This can probably be tidied up a little but I think you get the idea.

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b5t6j3z9/1/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll do this but with @Vectors suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write left:0

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19337/)

```
#myDiv.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Then the div does not go full width of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to calculate the measurement between the content and the window edge and then apply this as left padding when required.

```
var measure = ($(window).width() - ($('#myDiv').offset().left + $('#myDiv').width()));

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($('#myDivWrapper'))) {
    if (!initSet) {
      initSet = true;
    }
    $("#myDiv").removeClass('fixed').css('padding-left', 0);
  } else if (initSet) {
    $("#myDiv").addClass('fixed').css('padding-left', measure+'px');
  }
});
```

DEmo Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19338/

EDIT: If editing the markup is an option i'd recommend @Paulie_D 's approach. You don't need to add another container though - simply add a class to your existing markup.

Demo Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19340/

```
<div id="myDivWrapper">
    <div id="myDiv">
      <p class="container">
        This should be fixed once it comes into view and then goes out of view.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all your paragraphs are inside a `container` class, you can also add this class to your fixed paragraph as well.

```
    $("#myDiv").removeClass('fixed');
    $("#myDiv p").removeClass('container');
  ...
    $("#myDiv").addClass('fixed');
    $("#myDiv p").addClass('container');
```

Further more, you will need to tell `#myDiv`to go full width:

```
#myDiv.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

See working example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNddKY).

Comment: This will not enable the div to go full width. Notice how the red does not stretch to the windows edge.

Comment: @Vector thanks for your observation, I missunderstood that part. I have updated my solution.

Comment: No problem. You don't need to add/remove the `container` class on scroll. Simply add it on page load. http://codepen.io/kpldesigns/pen/EKEeXx